# How to make a row from list with last item with count of remaining items when overflow

Tags: flutter, widget

I need a `Row()` widget with a List of `Text()` widgets. But when it is overflowed, I must hide all overflowed items and add a last item with a number of remaining items.

Sample code to visualization:

```
Row(
  children: [
    ...texts.mapIndexed(
      (index, text) {
        return Text(text);
      },
    ),
    Remaining("remainingTextsLength"),
   ],
);
```

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: Please add sample of expected output image

Comment: Did you find any solution for your problem? I have same problem